# Cant find ReactNativeComponentTree file

Tags: react-native

I found that I can get the corresponed element via synthetic events by ReactNativeComponentTree

```
"dependencies": {
"native-base": "^2.8.1",
"react": "16.5.0",
"react-native": "0.57.0",
"react-native-fs": "^2.11.15"
}
```

These are my dependencies.

```
import ReactNativeComponentTree from 'react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNativeComponentTree';
```

I tried this import and it doesn't work.

I can't find ReactNativeComponentTree file in the path. Whats wrong here?

Comment: Is the file present in the path `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNativeComponentTree` ??

Comment: @pritesh no the file isn't present in the path.

Comment: In react-native .57 it is removed.In react-native .53 it is still there

Comment: Thanks bro I got it in  react-native .53 @pritesh